# Dialog not showing in the center

Tags: jquery

I have small piece of code; the jQuery Dialog appears in center for those elements who appear without scrolling, but when I scroll the page and click something the dialog goes down.

How do I set this?

Comment: please recreate the issue in a snippet or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see what you are talking about...

Comment: Please do what @Banana said or attach some code. We can’t help you if we’re in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctlly you want fixed position dialog box. add following css class to your css:-

```
.ui-dialog
{
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/1853/)